# How to create reminders and reoccurring tasks in SharePoint Designer 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I was assigned a SharePoint 2016 project in which the requirements are quite custom and since I've never worked on such a project I'm needing a bit of help. I'm currently using the SharePoint Designer 2013 to create the workflow that will run the custom list I've created.

**Currently, I'm not receiving the reminder notifications and the tasks aren't auto-recreating.**

The requirements are:

- Create reminder notifications based on Due Date (i.e., 30 days, 15 days, 5 days, Due Date, Past Due)
- Set a tasks to auto-create based on frequency of task (i.e., Annual, Monthly, Daily, Semi-Annual)***

I realize this might be a bit much and could be that some functionality might not exist but I was able to get some started based on simple googling. I've attached screenshots of my workflow thus far. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y47E.png)

[Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hjc7.png)

[Part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2TRe.png)

Comment: It would be really nice to add some details about where your current workflow is failing, where are you stuck,  any error messages?

Comment: I apologize. So currently, I'm not receiving the reminder notifications nor is the task re-creating when I update the action status.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use any alert&reminder web part from VirtoSoftware or PlumSail or KWizCom. It's possible to create a reminder based on due date with all these tools.